# Can I assign enums to closure parameters in Swift

Tags: swift

I was reading this article http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/reducers/ when I found a puzzling piece of swift I realized I couldn't quite understand.

Given these enums

```
enum Message {
    case inputChanged(String?)
    case ratesAvailable(data: Data?)
    case reload
}

enum Command {
   case load(URL, onComplete: (Data?) -> Message)
}
```

in the following function

```
mutating func send(_ message: Message) -> Command? {
    switch message {
    case .inputChanged(let input):
        inputAmount = input.flatMap { Double($0) }
        return nil
    case .ratesAvailable(data: let data):
         guard let data = data,
             let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
             let dict = json as? [String:Any],
             let dataDict = dict["rates"] as? [String:Double],
             let rate = dataDict[Currency.usd.rawValue] else { return nil }
         self.rate = rate
        return nil
    case .reload:
         return .load(ratesURL(), onComplete: Message.ratesAvailable)
     }
}
```

In the last line of this function. How can the enum **Message.ratesAvailable** can be assigned as the clousure parameter defined in the Command enum associated value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Message.ratesAvailable` has type `(Data?) -> Message`

which you can [see for yourself](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/596e5304d79b221abf10c85e):

```
import Foundation

enum Message {
    case inputChanged(String?)
    case ratesAvailable(data: Data?)
    case reload
}

print(type(of: Message.ratesAvailable)) // => (Optional<Data>) -> Message
```

Comment: Huh...had no idea the associated values were setup like that

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Yep. It's odd, but it's nice. It's a clever way to set this up, with minimal compiler magic. The more of the language that can be defined in terms of the language, the better.

Comment: I think it is a variant of [Instance Methods are Curried Functions in Swift](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)

Comment: @MartinR Not really, but that's an interesting thing to note, anyway

Comment: Except They removed Currying. 

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I'm a fan, because it's more likely to need to pass an instance method as a function that takes the instance+args, than to need to pass it as a curried function that takes the instance, then the args

Comment: I tend to agree. Currying is sort of a weird concept to understand to have language level support. And t's goal can be accomplished with a library anyway: https://github.com/thoughtbot/Curry

Comment: I guess that I am not used to think of enums in that function like fashion where in this case given a Data? I get a Message. So this means that when the clousure is executed all it is doing is returning the Message.ratesAvailable with the value passed in the call as a parameter assigned to the associated value of the enum right?

Comment: @AndyNorcisa Yep.